# Postgresql, how to add multiple table for one trigger

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

I have a question: how to add multiple table for one trigger?
Is that possible, or should I just make another 2 triggers for 2 different tables?

Answer (score 18):

Create a new function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updated_timestamp_func()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
'
BEGIN
    NEW.updated_at = now();
    RETURN NEW;
END;
';
```

Then create a trigger for each table that has the column **updated_at**

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    t text;
BEGIN
    FOR t IN
        SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_name = 'updated_at'
    LOOP
        EXECUTE format('CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_timestamp
                    BEFORE UPDATE ON %I
                    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE updated_timestamp_func()', t,t);
    END loop;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: Thanks I was looking for this. But I need to execute a trigger on every table in my public schema that contains a specific column name. How would I select all these tables in my public schema?

Answer (score 3):

Iterate one trigger for all tables
(For Example Foreign Tables)

```sql
DO
$$
DECLARE
  r RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN SELECT *
           FROM information_schema.tables
           where table_type = 'FOREIGN TABLE'
                 and table_schema = 'public'
                 and table_name <> 'django_migrations'
  LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'CREATE TRIGGER FOR: %', r.table_name::text;

    EXECUTE 'CREATE TRIGGER trg_insert_ids
      BEFORE INSERT
      on ' || r.table_name || ' FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_ids();';
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a trigger for each table, so if you have two tables, you need two triggers.

However, multiple triggers can use the same trigger function.

Comment: Thx, I thought, perhaps there was some function for that, anyway thx for answer.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is maybe to late but I've another way to use only 1 trigger for multiple table.

I've multiple production table and each one of them have an insert trigger who call my trig_data_production_add().

In this function, I use TG_TABLE_NAME to know wich table is calling the trigger, here is an example :

```
        IF (TG_TABLE_NAME = 'production_alimentation') THEN
            prot_cmd_var = 47;
        ELSIF (TG_TABLE_NAME = 'production_froid') THEN
            prot_cmd_var = 16;
        ELSIF (TG_TABLE_NAME = 'production_chauffage') THEN
            prot_cmd_var = 9;
        ELSIF (TG_TABLE_NAME = 'production_electrique_puissance' OR TG_TABLE_NAME = 'production_electrique_consommation') THEN
            prot_cmd_var = 20;
```

By doing this, i can insert in a "production_stats" with common informations like id_device or id_user, but with differents values of prot_cmd_var

Hope this can help someone